# Open File From a Directory

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a function that allows you to select a file from a given directory, the function is called openFile. Any ideas on how I'd do that? I've got a start on it but anything I enter seems to come out as it not being in the directory. The output never comes out as opening the file. Just a little lost on the whole thing. I don't think I need to change anything besides the openFile function in the code. The rest of the code was provided by our textbook.

```
"""
Program: filesys.py
Author: Ken

Provides a menu-driven tool for navigating a file system
and gathering information on files.
"""

import os, os.path

QUIT = '7'

COMMANDS = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')

MENU = """1   List the current directory
2   Move up
3   Move down
4   Number of files in the directory
5   Size of the directory in bytes
6   Search for a file name
7   Quit the program
8   View a file in the current directory"""


def main():
    while True:
        print(os.getcwd())
        print(MENU)
        command = acceptCommand()
        runCommand(command)
        if command == QUIT:
            print("Have a nice day!")
            break

def openFile(dirName):
    """Allows user to view list of files in directory and view them."""
    lyst = os.listdir(dirName)
    for element in lyst: print(element)
    userinput = open(input('Enter file name: '))
    if userinput == os.listdir:
        open(userinput)
    else:
        print('\nFile not in directory\n')

def acceptCommand():
    """Inputs and returns a legitimate command number."""
    while True:
        command = input("Enter a number: ")
        if not command in COMMANDS:
            print("Error: command not recognized")
        else:
            return command

def runCommand(command):
    """Selects and runs a command."""
    if command == '1':
        listCurrentDir(os.getcwd())
    elif command == '2':
        moveUp()
    elif command == '3':
        moveDown(os.getcwd())
    elif command == '4':
        print("The total number of files is", \
              countFiles(os.getcwd()))
    elif command == '5':
        print("The total number of bytes is", \
              countBytes(os.getcwd()))
    elif command == '6':
        target = input("Enter the search string: ")
        fileList = findFiles(target, os.getcwd())
        if not fileList:
            print("String not found")
        else:
            for f in fileList:
                print(f)
    elif command == '8':
        openFile(os.getcwd())

def listCurrentDir(dirName):
    """Prints a list of the cwd's contents."""
    lyst = os.listdir(dirName)
    for element in lyst: print(element)

def moveUp():
    """Moves up to the parent directory."""
    os.chdir("..")

def moveDown(currentDir):
    """Moves down to the named subdirectory if it exists."""
    newDir = input("Enter the directory name: ")
    if os.path.exists(currentDir + os.sep + newDir) and \
       os.path.isdir(newDir):
        os.chdir(newDir)
    else:
        print("ERROR: no such name")

def countFiles(path):
    """Returns the number of files in the cwd and
    all its subdirectories."""
    count = 0
    lyst = os.listdir(path)
    for element in lyst:
        if os.path.isfile(element):
            count += 1
        else:
            os.chdir(element)
            count += countFiles(os.getcwd())
            os.chdir("..")
    return count

def countBytes(path):
    """Returns the number of bytes in the cwd and
    all its subdirectories."""
    count = 0
    lyst = os.listdir(path)
    for element in lyst:
        if os.path.isfile(element):
            count += os.path.getsize(element)
        else:
            os.chdir(element)
            count += countBytes(os.getcwd())
            os.chdir("..")
    return count

def findFiles(target, path):
    """Returns a list of the file names that contain
    the target string in the cwd and all its subdirectories."""
    files = []
    lyst = os.listdir(path)
    for element in lyst:
        if os.path.isfile(element):
            if target in element:
                files.append(path + os.sep + element)
        else:
            os.chdir(element)
            files.extend(findFiles(target, os.getcwd()))
            os.chdir("..")
    return files

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `os.path.join(dirName, file)` to build the path?

Comment: What do you expect `if userinput == os.listdir:` to do?

Comment: @KlausD. I was hoping it would allow me to scan the printed directory to see if the file the user types is in said directory

Comment: The try `if userinput in os.listdir():`. Don't forget **to call** functions. Sorry, but the lines around it don't look promising as well. There are too many errors in the code to handle them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In openFile your checking if userinput (A string) is equal to os.listdir (A function), instead check `if userinput in lyst:` or `if userinput in os.listdir(dir):`

Comment: I imagine OP also intended `userinput` to be defined as `userinput = input('Enter file name: ')` (without the `open` function).